# How do i add social sharing to the images pulling from flickr?

Tags: javascript, gallery, flickr

*How do i add social sharing (fb,twitter,instagram) to the individual images pulling from flickr?*

Refer to codepen: http://goo.gl/2b8OTY

please help!
Thanks..

Comment: What have you already tried? What happened?

Comment: I do not know how to add in social media sharing to be implemented with the image itself. Can u help?

Comment: Consider [CodeMentor](https://www.codementor.io/). Your question is too broad for Stack Overflow.